# difference between tables and what changed?

Tags: mysql

Our marketing team keeps track for their campaign of what they call "key" accounts. The data is updated every Monday and last week's data archived to a "snapshot" table. The structure is quite simple

```
'AccountID','ContactID','Tag','Last Modified Date'
'602','31262001','Key','2018-08-07 22:43:57'
'608','91285974','Key','2018-08-07 22:43:55'
'608','28620737','Key','2018-08-07 22:43:57'
'4002','118697713','Key','2018-09-08 06:46:49'
'9481','112536097','Key','2018-08-07 22:43:56'
```

Every Monday, I have to report on

1. customer accounts in last week not in this week
2. customer accounts in this week not in last week
3. customer accounts where the "Tag" is not 'Key'

For 1) and 2) , I did this

```
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM current_week t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN snapshot t2 ON t1.AccountID = t2.AccountID AND t1.ContactID 
 = t2.ContactID
 WHERE t2.Tag = 'Key'
 UNION
 SELECT t2.*
 FROM current_week t1
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN snapshot t2 ON t1.AccountID = t2.AccountID AND t1.ContactID 
 = t2.ContactID
 WHERE t2.Tag = 'Key';
```

NB: For some reason, marketing is allowing an account to 1:M ContactID values and this seems to create false positives in my data. I added the join for that reason.

But I am not sure how to do 3). Any idea?

Comment: I think even your queries for 1) and 2) are not correct. Are you sure that you are getting correct results ? And for 3) just do a `t2.Tag != 'Key'`

Comment: You've given example table structure, but not example data for both tables and the expected results for each of your three scenarios given those sample data for both tables -- could you please update your question with `current_week` and `snapshot` data sets, and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with only one `UNION ALL`.

The first query adds 'Key' tags that are missing in snapshot, and also gets those that are not a 'Key' tag.
And then let the second query just add those that are only in the snapshot.

```
SELECT curr.*
FROM current_week AS curr
LEFT JOIN snapshot AS prev ON (prev.AccountID = curr.AccountID AND prev.ContactID = curr.ContactID)
WHERE (curr.Tag != 'Key' OR (curr.Tag = 'Key' AND prev.Tag is null))

UNION ALL

SELECT prev.*
FROM snapshot AS prev
LEFT JOIN current_week AS curr ON (curr.AccountID = prev.AccountID AND curr.ContactID = prev.ContactID)
WHERE curr.Tag is null

ORDER BY AccountID;
```

You can test it on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f0d27ff54dee506f9251f6f5d3977b9)*

Comment: My apologies for the belated response. My logic was actually incorrect but you pointed me in the right direction. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.

Comment: @AB Thx anyway.  Btw, you probably are already aware. But realise the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. A `UNION` can be slighty slower because it has to sort the combined results to be able to remove duplicate records.  While a `UNION ALL` simply sticks them together, dups or not.